# C# MVC Get full file path

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, activex

First of all I will state that I digged half of the Internet for this and everywhere I find:"No You cannot it is web browser security".
I need this for Intranet webpage in ASP. NET MVC5 + C#.
User should be allowed to select file or folder in some kind of dialog. Then when selected I would like to get back the path of slected item [also files or folders on network drives. But instead of mapped path like z:\... I prefer \\Server50\folder\folder2\file.ext]
Then I want to send this path to SQL DB for some actions. (that's easy part)
That's the reason I want full UNC path. No files to be uploaded.
Can anyone give me some kind of clue where to look for or start?

Comment: Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As you have already discovered on half of the internet, for security reasons, what you are trying to achieve is not possible. You could achieve this with proprietary ActiveX installed component on the client machine.

Comment: I do not believe in "not possible" situations. If so many people ask about it there has to be a solution. I will search then for ActiveX solution.

Comment: Don't use ActiveX. It's a dead technology. http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2015/05/microsofts-new-browser-edge-will-mark-the-end-of-activex-and-vbscript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is possible now for intranet purposes;]
I used MVC+Silverlight+certificate on client side

Adding Silverlight Project to Visual Studio Solution:

`right-click` on MVC app Project->`Properties`
`SilverLight Application tab`-> `Add...`:
-check `Copy to configuration specific folder`
-uncheck `Add a test page...`
-check `enable Silverlight debugging`
Silver light:in .xaml.cs main page:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.Drop += new DragEventHandler(drop);//important to add
    }

    private void drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data!=null)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as FileInfo[];
            foreach(var item in files)
             {
                 //fullpath in: item.Fullname property
              }
        }
    }
```

in xaml main page design

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFBF6666" AllowDrop="true">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"     Margin="72,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
 </Grid>
```

`right-click` Silverlight Project->`Properties`
`Signing` tab-> check `Sign the xap file`->`Create the test certificate`

View setup in MVC app:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
 <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="1000" height="800">
    <param name="source" value="/ClientBin/System.xap" />
    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="background" value="white" />
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
      <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none" />
    </a>
 </object>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Rebuild both projects
Deploy to production server
Install created certificate on client side in `...trusted root authorities`

Now it is working;]
I saw some people adding .xap, .xaml extension to web.config but for me it did not help.