# File input filepath dropzone.js

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I've been struggling with this for quite a long time. I would like to get the input filepath in MVC.

Can anyone please explain why `input type="file"` in IE shows the full path of file after submit, but when used with dropzone.js I get only the file name? (I know there may be security features but it goes through with the input).

I am really tired of this problem now but I need the filepath of a file. I also looked for a Silverlight solution but found SL communication with JS using input (it looks like its going in a circle).

Can anyone give me a clue or an example solution?

My desired solution is to have drag&drop `<input type="file" multiple/>` also working with folders (get folder path).

Comment: As far as i know, and as you said, for security reasons is not possible to pass the file path from dropzone to a regular file input, I think is a browser feature. Any particular reason to not use dropzone directly in this case?

Comment: Well, no reason, Actually I do not want to upload file. I only want full file path like in input element. It is for inranet purpose only. But to make more robust I want to add drag&drop and folders support. I read a lot of stackoverflow posts and other forums. I have no clue at the moment.

Comment: Other solution here:<br>
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456787/c-sharp-mvc-get-full-file-path/34952566#34952566](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456787/c-sharp-mvc-get-full-file-path/34952566#34952566)